# Can someone explain how this is returning the key value pair of the object? Thanks

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**What does !result do here?**

I don't understand how the object comes into play here. Could someone please explain how it's actually creating the key value pairs here?

```
let a = [5,5,5,5,2,2,2,6,9];

let result = {};

for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if(!result[a[i]])
    result[a[i]] = 0;
    result[a[i]]++;
  }

 console.log(result);


Returns this object: { '2': 3, '5': 4, '6': 1, '9': 1 }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: maybe formatting the code would help a bit, because the increment is outside of the if statement. so in short if a property of the object is not given or falsy, it creates one with the value zero. this value can be incremented later.

Comment: As per my understanding, You have not added `{ }` after `if(!result[a[i]])`, which means, if the condition is true, only `result[a[i]] = 0;` will be executed, and `result[a[i]]++;` will always be executed, no matter if condition is true or false

Answer (score 0):

`!` means `not` or `false` i.e, the code means if there is no such key in the `result` object, then do the operation, i.e, add that key. After that just increment it.

Comment: Thanks! How does the key get added from the above code? From my understanding, the object is currently empty and there's no current key or value. Is !result[a[i]] checking to see if there's a value in the array, then creating a key for it? Then, incrementing each time it comes across that key? Thanks!

Comment: By saying that it adds a new key i mean that it adds a key and a value to the key.....

Answer (score 0):

First result is an object as you've declared on top the snippet.

```
result = {};
```

If statement `result[a[i]]` checks wheather property `a[i]` exist in `result` object or not. If not then creates a new property `a[i]`(5 if i = 0).

So `result[a[i]]++` `result[a[i]] = result[a[i]]  + 1`

Let's break `result[a[i]]`  with `i = 0`

- `[i]` is index let say `i` as `0`
- `a[i]` is the element at `i` positon in array `a`. so here `a[i]` is `5`.
- `result[a[i]]` means create a new property `a[i]` i.e `5` in result object.

Next, Let say you are at index `i = 3`, till now a new `result` has already a property `5` which has value `4`